# Show 4 lines of employee bio with "Read More" button to expand content for array of bios using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, arrays, bootstrap-4

I created a Google App Script that connects to a Google Sheet acting as a database.

The app loops through each row and I display each column as part of an entry in an employee bio page.

- ex. Picture | Name | Title | Phone | Email | Bio

Everything is being displayed correctly but some of the bios are long so I want to truncate the bio text to on page load only show 4 lines of text with the rest hidden. Then, on a click of a "Read More" button, display the remaining text.

I'm using Bootstrap so Bootstrap Collapse seems like the obvious fit but when I've tried to implement it, only the first entry works since the IDs associated with the link and the button are unique to that entry

You can find a working example of the directory here:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyldNdLB7HyJvf6b1FPmyLgzsdzpWYZnCbZRj1-ojbUe5Km_dSvHoW6D43O4mZ3rLAW/exec

My thought is to use the Boostrap Collapse and somehow create unique IDs for each bio entry's Button and collapseID.

I've tried using this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g4q5vp2f/1/  as a guide but I run into the issue of not having unique IDs for the `<p id="collapseExample">` and the `<a role="button" href="collapseExample" aria-controls="collapseExample">`

```css
#module {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#module #collapseExample.collapse:not(.show) {
  display: block;
  height: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#module #collapseExample.collapsing {
  height: 3rem;
}

#module a.collapsed::after {
  content: '+ Show More';
}

#module a:not(.collapsed)::after {
  content: '- Show Less';
}
```

```html
<div id="module" class="container">
  <h3>Bacon Ipsum</h3>
  <p class="collapse" id="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false">
    Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner picanha tri-tip biltong leberkas salami meatball tongue filet mignon landjaeger tail. Kielbasa salami tenderloin picanha spare ribs, beef ribs strip steak jerky cow. Pork chop chicken ham hock beef ribs turkey jerky. Shoulder
    beef capicola doner, tongue tail sausage short ribs andouille. Rump frankfurter landjaeger t-bone, kielbasa doner ham hock shankle venison. Cupim capicola kielbasa t-bone, ball tip chicken andouille venison pork chop doner bacon beef ribs kevin shankle.
    Short loin leberkas tenderloin ground round shank, brisket strip steak ham hock ham.
  </p>
  <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
</div>
```

Goal:

Loop through each employee bio and be able to show/hide truncated bio text

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was loop through the collection of posts and index each one then assign the index value as a number to the id, href and aria-controls.

It looks something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < tableData.Length; i++) {
<div id="module" class="container">
  <h3>Bacon Ipsum</h3>
  <p class="collapse" id="collapseExample<? i ?>" aria-expanded="false">
    Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner picanha tri-tip biltong leberkas salami meatball tongue filet mignon landjaeger tail. Kielbasa salami tenderloin picanha spare ribs, beef ribs strip steak jerky cow. Pork chop chicken ham hock beef ribs turkey jerky. Shoulder
    beef capicola doner, tongue tail sausage short ribs andouille. Rump frankfurter landjaeger t-bone, kielbasa doner ham hock shankle venison. Cupim capicola kielbasa t-bone, ball tip chicken andouille venison pork chop doner bacon beef ribs kevin shankle.
    Short loin leberkas tenderloin ground round shank, brisket strip steak ham hock ham.
  </p>
  <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample<? i ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample<? i ?>"></a>
</div>

};
```